# How to access data from web3.eth.Contracts.send() function?

Tags: web3js, transactions, contract-invocation

If I run this chunk of code from my async function I will get a transaction receipt as an output:

```
const response = await contract.methods.recoverAddr(hex_msg, 
v_decimal,r, s).send({from: accounts[0]}).then(console.log);
```

Whereas if I run the same chunk of code but with a call() instead of send(), I will get an address which I wanted. My question is: how do I actually access that address in my send() method?

Comment: `send` returns a transaction receipt. You should use it for functions which change the state of your contract. For constant function (`pure` or `view`), you should use `call`, which returns the value returned from the constant function.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and I've been reading into it. My follow up question is: Does the `call`  prove the integrity of my data anyways? For example, if I wanted to use this contract for proving any kind of data coming from any eth address, don't I have to use `send` so that my transaction gets put onto the blockchain? Or it still stays fundamentally the same regardless of type of data/different address? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, hope you understand what I'm trying to say.